# Online code editors programming language

Tags: javascript, ide, text-editor

When searching for online code editors (out of interest how all the course sites such as Codecademy has been made) I noticed they are all been written in JavaScript.

Why are all those code editors such as CodeMirror or Ace written in JavaScript and not in PHP or Java for web applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP and Java are processed Server-Side. JavaScript is processed by the web browser.
If you were processing in real-time with PHP, you would need a piece of JavaScript (such as an AJAX POST) to send the entire chunk of code to the server for re-processing, wait for a return and then replace the entire display with newly formatted text every time a user changes a single character.

JavaScript can do this all itself directly in the web browser and leverage the power of the User’s PC to accomplish the task.

Using JavaScript speeds up the process as nothing ends to be passed backwards and forwards all the time, it lowers bandwidth usage as nothing is passed to and fro and it also reduces the server workload for the same reason.

There is also an argument that it is more reliable and secure. If you are not passing anything back to a server, there is no need to worry as much about properly "escaping" special characters, less of a concern about an insecure piece of server-side code being exploited etc.

It is also good practise to not send anything back and put a load on your server unless there is a good reason to do so.

While you could have a button on your "code editor" which would send an entire chunk of script back to a server for processing and send back a formatted return, it's generally not the done thing for the reason stated above. Also, a "reformat all" button wouldn't add much value as you can simply reformat everything in JavaScript.

Comment: Alright, thank you :). What @philipp said about an Java applet, does that run on the user's computer aswell?

Comment: Java applets are akward, they can be either!  You can even have a Java Applet running on the server which accepts socket connections from a Client-side java applet.

Comment: Ah okay, i asked it because i dont really like JS, so trying to found an alternative. But if it's the only way which is efficient i'll just do it like that

Comment: There is HTML5, flash, you could do a client-side java applet, silverlight, there are multiple alternatives to JavaScript

Comment: Alright, but those client-side java applets, what is that? Can you proccess HTML code with it?

Comment: A Client-Side Java Applet is exactly that.. its a small compiled piece of code which can execute is a web browser. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/applet_create.htm  A java applet can process HTML, JS, whatever you teach it to process.

Comment: Alright, but if you look at the course sites, how do they do it? I figured out Codecademy uses Ace, but you cant procces assignment's with JS right?

Comment: You probably can't do a full assignment and mark it with Javascript alone - the chances are that it will be a piece of Javascript which passes the completed code back to a server-side script for a parse check, string compare, whatever they do and then returns a yes/no value

Comment: Alright thank you :) I suppose that is possible with Java aswell?

Comment: Yes, but you'd need socket connections and an interpereter on both sides, so jearning JS would probably be easier.

Answer (score 3):

PHP or Java Servlets are purely server-sided technologies. They can't do anything unless the user clicks on a link. When you want any interactivity while the website is displayed, you need Javascript, at least for an AJAX call to a PHP/JSP backend.

When you want an application like a code editor the user is interacting with very closely, you want as much of it as possible to run on the user machine. This improves the user experience due to better responsiveness and means less strain on your server resources. When you want a rich application in a web browser, you can either use plugins like Flash, Silverlight or Java applets the user might or might not have installed, up-to-date and enabled. Or you can just use Javascript which - thanks to HTML5 - became almost as powerful as the plugin solutions.

Comment: Alright, so you can't actually control the input or looks of the 'code editor' with the server-side technologologies languages?

Comment: @Bas only in a very limited way. You could, for example, have a "auto-format" button which submits the whole content of the editor window to the server when clicked and then have the server respond by returning the complete HTML document with the content formated. But that would be a lot slower than doing it with Javascript on the client-side.

Comment: I see. So no one does this kind of things with any of those languages?

Comment: It's not necessarily that nobody does it, but that when you have the choice of JavaScript (available everywhere and not reliant on plugins), Java (#1 most exploited plugin), Flash (#2 most exploited plugin) and Silverlight (not available on all platforms) the needs of the solution dictate the tools used.

Comment: @JamesSnell What do you mean by exploited plugin?

Comment: @Bas Both Java applets and Flash had various security vulnerabilities in the past which allowed websites to do stuff on the users computer they were not supposed to be doing. For that reason some users have them disabled completely or only enable them on websites they trust.

Comment: @Bas as Philipp says, for years both Java and Flash have had flaws which make them vulnerable to viruses and malware that are 'in the wild'.  New flaws are found often as quickly as they can be patched and for developer purposes you may as well consider them constantly insecure.

Comment: But an Java applet isn't the same as using the Java with the JSP pages right?

Comment: Right - Java with JSP runs on the server, an applet runs on the client.

Comment: Just to be clear: The recent bad press about Java security was only in the context of malicious Java applets. They are a danger for users who visit malicious websites. From the perspective of the webmaster, Java is perfectly save for both servlets and applets (unless, or course, you build your own security vulnerabilities). When your users trust you, it is not unreasonable to ask them to enable Java for your website.

Answer (score 1):

Besides those facts mentioned already, I would like to add that at the heart of all major browsers there is a powerful EcmaScript/JavaScript engine, incredibly improved by years and years of evolution of the Web.

Therefore all major browsers natively speak this language and are capable of running programs in it in the most efficient way. Why in the world would you use something else to write a client-side program intended to run within one of these beasts?

Even when the browsers only speak this language is not like you are forced to use JavaScript to write your programs. Over the years several other languages have been created to try to replace or "improve" JavaScript. You could write your programs in one of these languages and then a compiler translates your code to JavaScript in order to run it in the browser, which is ultimately, what the browser understands.

Examples of these alternative languages are the now decadent [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org) which translates Java to JavaScript. Other more modern approaches like [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) and more recently [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org). With the renewd popularity of functional programming these days we have seen the appearance of [ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript) and Google has not gotten tired of failing trying to dethrone JavaScript and created the awesome [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org) programming language for that matter (even one of their browsers named [Dartium](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dartium/) has a native engine for it). And believe me, Google is not done failing and as we talk they are already working in another one of these called [AtScript](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11YUzC-1d0V1-Q3V0fQ7KSit97HnZoKVygDxpWzEYW0U/mobilebasic). Finally, now thanks to the effort in [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) you can even port your programs from C/C++. All of these are languages that are ultimately complied to JavaScript in order to run the code in the browser.

So, as you can see it is not like you are forced to "write" your client-side programs in JavaScript, you are just forced to "run" them in JavaScript because that is what most browsers understand.